# The link wont toggle the next div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Until now i searched a lot of times about this problem and i have found a lot. But nothing have worked for me. So now i make my own question..

Html

```
<article class="user">
    <section class="userBar">
        <p>
            <span class="arrow"><a class='arrow' href='#infos'>↓</a></span>
        </p>
    </section>
    <div class="hiddenInfos">
        <p>Here are the infos</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

JQuery..

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a.arrow').click(function() {
        $(this).next('div.hiddenInfos').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

I have tried a lot of thinks like:

1. .parent()
2. .siblings()
3. .closest()

So nothing want toggle my div element when i click at the arrow.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL3Lj741/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a.arrow').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.userBar').next('div.hiddenInfos').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

or you can use

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('a.arrow').click(function() {
            $(this).closest('.user').find('div.hiddenInfos').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
```

or you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('a.arrow').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().next('div.hiddenInfos').slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
```

Comment: I'm not a pro as you think .. We all still learning .. and We are here to help each others .. everything is simple if you decided to learn it .. very good luck to you :)